# Display button when input is not empty | not working JS

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want a button with the text 'Go!' to display next to my html input when a user types something in. If the input is empty the button must not be seen. I am using Javascript to try and do this but it doesn't seem to be working, what am I doing wrong?

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');

var input = document.getElementById("inputtext");
if(input.value === ""){
 alert("Input a value to continue");
 b.style.display = "none";
}else{
 b.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter name">
<button id="button">GO!
</button>
```

Comment: You executing your code when the page loads and that's it. You would need to check the input field when it loses focus.

Comment: Your code only runs once. If you want it to run when a user types something in, you'll need to attach it to an event handler (I suggest the `input` event of the `input` element).

Comment: Side note - it's generally considered bad for usability and accessibility for controls to appear and disappear — consider making the button present but disabled until the input is valid, then enable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making this work in JS you can use the input listener as :

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById("inputtext");
b.style.display = "none";

if(input.value === ""){
 alert("Input a value to continue");
}
 
input.addEventListener('input', function() {

if(input.value === ""){
 alert("Input a value to continue");
 b.style.display = "none";
}
else{

  b.style.display = "inline-block";
 }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter name">
<button id="button">GO!
</button>
```

Anothe solution using CSS is:-

```css
#inputtext:placeholder-shown ~ button{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter name">
<button id="button">GO!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the code below. You need to listen for a change event or a keydown event to fire the function.

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById("inputtext");

input.addEventListener("input", displayButton); // Event to listen for a change

function displayButton() {
  if(input.value === ""){
   alert("Input a value to continue"); // Remove this because it's bad user experience, use console.log if it's for testing.
   //b.style.display = "none"; // Disable the button for accessibility instead of hidding
   b.disabled = true;
  }else{
   //b.style.display = "inline-block";
   b.disabled = false;
  }
}

displayButton(); // Run the code at load time
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter name">
<button id="button">GO!
</button>
```